# How to route to another parent route from a nested route in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having a Parent Container like this:

```
   <Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route path="/website" component={Website} />
         <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Switch>
   </Router>
```

And both the `Website` and `Dashboard` components has another set of routes.

```
   <Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route path="/page-one" component={PageOne} />
         <Route path="/page-two" component={PageTwo} />
      </Switch>
   </Router>
   
   //dash
   <Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route path="/dash-page-one" component={DashOne} />
         <Route path="/dash-page-two" component={DashTwo} />
      </Switch>
   </Router>
```

And Inside `PageOne` again, I have a child component, from where I want to navigate to `<Dashboard />` (another parent) component but it didn't leave the current page, but the route changed.

```
   function(){
      <Link to="/dashboard">
         Go to dashboard.
      </Link>
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should only render the router component once by wrapping it around the root of your app, than you should be able to split the the routes navigating to anything inside the router. By creating separate router instances you are in essence creating separate routing environments.